# Set columns in Azure EventHubTrigger Function app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'd like to set the first two columns of an Azure Table (PartitionKey and RowKey) based on some variables I'm sending to the IoT Hub but I'm unsure how given my low familiarity with C#. My current code is the following:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

public static void Run(DataPoint myIoTHubMessage, out DataPoint outputTable, TraceWriter log)
{
   log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");

   myIoTHubMessage.PartitionKey = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
   myIoTHubMessage.RowKey = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

   outputTable = myIoTHubMessage;
}

public class DataPoint : TableEntity
{
   public string cameraName { get; set; }
   public string dateTime { get; set; }
   public double Area { get; set; }
}
```

Here I managed to set these rows to the current date and time, but my will is to set them to other variables received, such as `cameraName` and `dateTime` for instance, without duplicating them (I managed to do that with the following two lines, but that just duplicates columns):

```
   myIoTHubMessage.PartitionKey = myIoTHubMessage.cameraName;
   myIoTHubMessage.RowKey = myIoTHubMessage.dateTime;
```

Is there any way to have just the 3 variables as columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood You correctly, but You want to have output with 3 properties:
PartitionKey, RowKey and Area?

If yes, then try to define new class for output and use it to return data:

```
public static void Run(DataPoint myIoTHubMessage, out OutPutData outputTable, TraceWriter log)
{
   log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");

    outputTable = new OutPutData
    {
        PartitionKey = myIoTHubMessage.cameraName,
        RowKey = myIoTHubMessage.dateTime,
        Area = myIoTHubMessage.area
    };
}

public class DataPoint : TableEntity
{
   public string cameraName { get; set; }
   public string dateTime { get; set; }
   public double Area { get; set; }
}

public class OutPutData : TableEntity
{
   public double Area { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks!! By the way, is the Timestamp column mandatory or can I choose to remove it?

Comment: PartitionKey, RowKey and Timestamp are mandatory, but i think timestamp is automatically populated